Is there any working solution to get real activeSlide index SwiperJS while loop: true?
I got a SWiperJS slider with looping. I need to change text on section, considering by current active slide index. But when my slider reaches to the end i got indexes like (0,2). Is there any fix? code:
<script>
     const currentProductTitle = document.getElementById(
       "current-product-title",
     );
     
     const swiperProducts = new Swiper(".best-product-swiper__container", {
       direction: "horizontal",
       loop: false,

       navigation: {
         nextEl: ".best-product-swiper__next-btn",
         prevEl: ".best-product-swiper__prev-btn",
       },
       speed: 600,
     });
     swiperProducts.on("slideChange", function () {
       console.log(swiperProducts.activeIndex);
       switch (swiperProducts.activeIndex) {
         case 0:
           currentProductTitle.innerHTML = "DOG LEASH";
           break;
         case 1:
           if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 835px)").matches) {
             currentProductTitle.innerHTML = "DOG <br> BED";
           } else {
             currentProductTitle.innerHTML = "DOG BED";
           }
           break;
         case 2:
           currentProductTitle.innerHTML = "GPS COLLAR";
           break;
         case 3:
           currentProductTitle.innerHTML = "DOG HARNESS";
           break;
         case 4:
           currentProductTitle.innerHTML = "HAIR BRUSH";
           break;
         case 5:
           currentProductTitle.innerHTML = "DOG LEASH";
           break;
       }
     });
   </script>`


"But when my slider reaches to the end i got indexes like (0,2)" - can you clarify what you mean by that? According to the documentation, this should always be a number.

Friend, please make a minimal reproducible example of the problem, and we will help you.
